# Search result -> filename instead of name (For smart folders)

Tags: spotlight, mp3, smart-folders, id3-tag

Can anybody help me out. I want to create a smartfolder with all my `mp3`'s.
I renamed all my `mp3`'s to correct full name. For example:

```
Phil Collins - In The Air Tonight.mp3
```

When I create a smart folder. It shows all my `mp3`'s but with the name from metadata (ID3 tag) so only `In the air tonight`. There is no way to select filename in the colums. This is really annoying.

Does anybody know a solution? Or another program that does the trick? Or a hack?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot (or link to one) of the smart folder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can customize Finder in that way.

There is a third party program that does just what you want: [HoudahSpot](http://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot).
This lets you add columns for any attributes known to Spotlight. There are hundreds to choose from.

Filename is one of the columns you can add. By default, HoudahSpot and many other applications on OS X show the "display name". This can be a localized version of the file name or something entirely different. E.g. Apple Mail stores messages in numbered .emlx files. It stores the message subject with Spotlight.

*Full disclosure: I am the developer of HoudahSpot.*